# How to plot Lime report when there is a lot of features in data-set

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, mpld3, lime

I'm trying to plot lime report classification algorithm using the method `as_pyplot_figure()` for the explanation from LimeTabularExplainer. It is working but the data which i'm saving locally in html format using `save_html()` from mpld3 library which is coming as too compressed ( no visible actually).
Any other way to handle this scenario, will be helpful.

My code currently looks like

```
 from lime.lime_tabular import LimeTabularExplainer
    model= LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt', class_weight=None, 
    colsample_bytree=1.0,
    importance_type='split', learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=-1,
    min_child_samples=20, min_child_weight=0.001, min_split_gain=0.0,
    n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, num_leaves=31, objective=None,
    random_state=None, reg_alpha=0.0, reg_lambda=0.0, silent=True,
    subsample=1.0, subsample_for_bin=200000, subsample_freq=0)

    predict_function = model.predict

    explainer = LimeTabularExplainer(train_data,mode='classification')
    exp = explainer.explain_instance(
                    data, predict_function)
    fig = exp.as_pyplot_figure()
    
    mpld3.save_html(fig, lime_report.html)
```

Answer (score 1):

`exp.as_pyplot_figure()` returns a pyplot figure (barchart).

You should save that pyplot figure as below-

```
fig = exp.as_pyplot_figure()

fig.savefig('lime_report.jpg')
```

To save the LIME explanation in HTML format, the explanation object provides a method -

```
exp.save_to_file('lime_report.html')
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to load a saved explanation e.g. from as_list() back into a LIME exp object for visualisation?